# Expected number of steps until a queue of $n$ people has passed all $n$ ordered tests consecutively

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, expectation

We are given a queue of $n$ people $\{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$. They each have to pass $n$ exams $\{t_1, \ldots, t_n\}$. For simplicity we can "draw" the setting in the following way:
$$[t_n,t_{n-1}, \ldots, t_1, p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_{n} ]$$
On the left we have the $n$ tests each person standing in a queue on the right has to pass.

The rules are as follows:

a)  Each person can only write one exam at a time and one has to pass exam $t_i$ in order to write exam $t_{i+1}$.

b) Each exam $t_j$ can only be taken by maximally one person $p_l$ in the same step.

c) The probability that a person $p_k$ passes a test $t_i$ is $0.5$. In case of failure, the person $p_k$ has to take test $t_i$ again in the next step. In case of a pass, there are two possible cases in the next step. If someone in front of $p_k$ is taking the test $t_{i+1}$, then person $p_k$ has to wait (=does nothing). If the test $t_{i+1}$ is available, it moves on to test $t_{i+1}$ and takes it.

d) In each step, each person either takes a test or waits. A person waits $ \Leftrightarrow$ a person is infront of it. A person takes a test $\Leftrightarrow$ an available test is in front of it. In each step every person will perform an action (wait/take test).

Here is an example. Let us assume $n=3$, then we have $[ t_3,t_2,t_1,p_1,p_2,p_3]$ as a start setting. In the first step only $p_1$ can take the test $t_1$. If it passes it, it will look like this: $[ t_3,t_2,p_1,t_1,p_2,p_3]$. Now in the second step $p_1$ takes test $t_2$ and person $p_2$ takes test $t_1$. Assume now $p_1$ fails, but $p_2$ passes, then it looks like this: $[ t_3,t_2,p_1,p_2,t_1,p_3]$. Thus, in the third step $p_1$ has to retake test $t_2$, $p_2$ waits and $p_3$ takes test $t_1$.

I want to compute the expected number of steps until all people have passed all tests.

The way I have approached this problem is to think of it as a markov chain with one absorbing state. So that I can compute the expected time by writing down the transition matrix, deleting the row and column corresponding to the final state and inverting $I$ minus this matrix to get the expected times spent at each of the states. This does not give me a solution for general $n$ however since I have not managed to invert this matrix without fixing $n$ first. So I am hoping for a different solution.

I have done simulations for some $n$. It seems that the solution should be something like $E(n) = an + b$ for large $n$ where $a \in [6,7]$, but I am not sure as the program takes too long for larger values of $n$.

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The positions of the people act as  TASEP (see, e.g., https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.09855.pdf). It seems that the specialists (which I am not one of) know (at leasr asymptotic) answers to all such questions about it…